# When I create gatsby hot-reloading development environment on my server my IP address it will gives error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gatsby

When I create gatsby hot-reloading development environment on my server IP 
I run following commands

```
sudo gatsby develop --host http://34.211.109.30 --port 9000
```

then it will give following error.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://34.211.109.30
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

But my Ip is publicly accessible.but when I run this commands

```
gatsby build
```

Then it will listen on http://localhost:8000

Please anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

Drop the protocol. `--host` is just expecting an IP address.

This should be supported though — I created an issue to support supplying a protocol.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1652

Comment: Hello @Kyle Mathews When this issue will be resolved ?

Comment: Feel free to work on a fix for it! Would be a good first PR. Otherwise, will probably depend on someone else in the community picking it up.